# Trying to make one button for two different pages, login and profile page in android studio

Tags: java, android, button

I need help with this code. My intention is for if the user has not login yet, they click on the button, and login page will be displayed. Once they login then the app will display the profile page and retrieve the email to the main menu once they click on the home button. Once they click on the same button in the main menu, they will be brought to the profile page.

```
public void openProfile() {
    String getEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
    if (getEmail.isEmpty()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("email", getEmail);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I already solve this only by making a new variable hasAcc

```
public void openProfile() {
    int hasAcc = getIntent().getIntExtra("hasAcc", 0);
    if (hasAcc=0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("email", getEmail);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I don't know why it can't detect the email previously but when I toast it to another activity the email is shown

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please describe what doesn't work as expected in your code. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please read [ask] and its linked resources